# Why are several popular programming languages influenced by C?

Tags: programming-languages, c, history

The Top 10 programming languages, according to the [TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) seem to be heavily influenced by C:

**1. Java**

> The language derives much of its syntax from C and C++ but has a simpler object model and fewer low-level facilities. - *wikipedia.org*

**2. C**

> C is one of the most widely used programming languages of all time and there are very few computer architectures for which a C compiler does not exist. - *wikipedia.org*

**3. C#**

> During the development of the .NET Framework, the class libraries were originally written using a managed code compiler system called Simple Managed C (SMC). In January 1999, Anders Hejlsberg formed a team to build a new language at the time called Cool, which stood for "C-like Object Oriented Language". - *wikipedia.org*

**4. C++**

> It was developed by Bjarne Stroustrup starting in 1979 at Bell Labs as an enhancement to the C language. - *wikipedia.org*

**5. Objective-C**

> Objective-C is a reflective, object-oriented programming language that adds Smalltalk-style messaging to the C programming language. - *wikipedia.org*

**6. PHP**

> He rewrote these scripts as C programming language Common Gateway Interface (CGI) binaries, extending them to add the ability to work with Web forms and to communicate with databases and called this implementation "Personal Home Page/Forms Interpreter" or PHP/FI. - *wikipedia.org*

**8. Python**

> Python was conceived in the late 1980s and its implementation was started in December 1989 by Guido van Rossum at CWI in the Netherlands as a successor to the ABC programming language (itself inspired by SETL) capable of exception handling and interfacing with the Amoeba operating system. - *wikipedia.org*
>
> ABC (programming language)
> Its designers claim that ABC programs are typically around a quarter the size of the equivalent Pascal or C programs, and more readable. - *wikipedia.org*

**9. Perl**

> Perl borrows features from other programming languages including C, shell scripting (sh), AWK, and sed. - *wikipedia.org*

**10. JavaScript**

> JavaScript uses syntax influenced by that of C. - *wikipedia.org*

It appears that most of them borrow their syntax from C and / or are heavily influenced in several other ways, at least in their beginnings. Why?

Comment: Having c like syntax is not the same as being based on c.

Comment: In addition, TIOBE is a junk index.

Comment: Rather, can I ask why programming languages based on C are more popular?

Comment: @DeadMG: which is the better one?

Comment: @ManojR Please don't. That would be an extremely open ended question.

Comment: I've done some edits to remove the non constructive elements of the question. I'm not sure if I succeeded. Everyone please review, and let me now (your votes are feedback enough for me).

Comment: @YannisRizos good job (reverted my vote). Thinking about changing the title to **Why are popular programming languages severely influenced by C?** :)

Comment: @YannisRizos Great salvage of the question!  It is actually a great question now.

Comment: Because C is a descendant of ALGOL, and ALGOL is to block-scoped imperative labguages what Abraham is for Christians, Jews and Muslims.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a pretty solid question.

Comment: @GrahamLee: I never said I knew a better measurement. All I know is that TIOBE is worthless.

Comment: @GrahamLee FYI the reason TIOBE is worthless is that it's little more than a ranking of languages by the number of hits they return in search engines.

Comment: @DanNeely what makes that ranking worthless?

Comment: @GlennNelson some downvotes are remainders from initial question text which was later heavily edited by Yannis: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/135544/1

Comment: Your quotes about PHP and Python don't actually say they're influenced by C - and, while PHP is, Python doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The one to control them all

Comment: @gnat: significantly influenced

Comment: Yeah, Python doesn't really fit in on this list...

Comment: Python *is* influenced by C, but that doesn't mean it incorporates terribly many of its features - the influence is oftentimes negative, as in learning from previous mistakes. Python's design goes through great lengths to avoid common C pitfalls.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With the rise of UNIX in the 1970's, its standard systems programming language C quickly became the *lingua franca* of the programming world. For quite a while, C was practically mandatory for every programmer. As such, the fact that C has influenced almost every programming language that came after it in one way or another is hardly surprising, for two reasons:

- When designing a new language, it makes sense to base its syntax, where possible, on a popular existing language that can be assumed common knowledge.
- A new language is more likely to succeed if the learning curve is shallow, and a syntax that resembles an already known language is generally easier to learn (unless it behaves radically different despite the apparent similarities). So languages that borrow syntax from C generally gain traction more quickly than ones that don't.

But other languages existed, and they still do, some of them even predating C - there's the LISP family (CL, Clojure and Scheme being the most popular modern dialects), the ML family (with several modern dialects), there's a whole army of BASIC dialects (VB.NET and VBA are modern implementations), there's Pascal and its relatives (Delphi being the best known one) and many 'oddball' languages that took influences from many other languages and invented a few things themselves; examples include Go, Python, Lua, Haskell (and its predecessor, Miranda), Prolog, and Erlang. While none of these languages (except Python) is in your top 10, many of them have a stable user base and an active community; they're certainly not going away.

Also, it should be noted that the amount of C influence in these languages differs wildly, ranging from the almost 100% C compatible languages C++ and Objective-C, up to Python (which deliberately abandons many of C's syntax features). And that's only the syntax: in terms of semantics, most of the languages on that list don't have much in common with C. The overwhelming majority has memory management built into the language, and consequently, copy semantics, argument passing, etc., are very different. JavaScript, for example, has strong semantic influences from Scheme, while its syntax was designed to resemble Java (which, in turn bases its bits-and-pieces syntax on C, but not its semantics). Other differences (with the exception of C++ and Objective-C, which are mostly backwards-compatible with C) include error handling, scope rules, standard libraries, external code inclusion (`#include`), and the fact that many of these languages are 'virtualized', that is, they run on an interpreter, JIT compiler, or a virtual machine.

Python, by the way, does have some C influence, but it is certainly not "based on" C. Both syntax and semantics differ quite radically from C, and this is by design. Python only borrows features from C where other alternatives are equally "good" (as per the "Zen of Python" - type `import this` in a python interpreter).

As for the future of programming; predictions vary. The influence of C is not going away, but recent developments in hardware (multi-core machines becoming commonplace, powerful GPU's, the CPU ceasing to be the typical performance bottleneck, fast reliable network connections, etc.) call for radically different approaches to programming in general. Anyone who has ever written a multithreaded distributed application in an imperative language can tell that it's incredibly hard, while languages like Haskell have features that remove most of the typical problems and offer a more abstract and more structured approach to distributed, concurrent, and parallel processing (purity being an important concept in this context). Newer programming languages (e.g. C# or D) already include many features to support such an idiom. In any case, neither the strong impact C has made on programming, nor the existence of non-C-like languages is going away.

Comment: Nice answer, but "CPU ceasing to be the typical performance bottleneck"? In my experience, performance problems abound - CPU, IO, you name it. If not, profilers would not be needed, even though they are not very effective.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Usually, the bottlenecks I encounter are caused by I/O, networking, CPU cache performance, bus throughput, and (inefficient) interprocess communication. Back in the days, the CPU was almost inevitably the bottleneck; this just isn't true anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot like asking why English is the dominant language in the US.  Why not Spanish or French? They controlled more of the US territory than the English colonies.  Why not Dutch?  The first US capital was in a former Dutch colony.  I'm not sure there can possibly be an "answer" to this.

However, the "Computer Languages History" timeline (http://www.levenez.com/lang/) provides all the answer there can possibly be.

Comment: Because Great Britain from the 1600-1880 roughly was the prime industrial and financial powerhouse of the world, followed by the United States from 1880-Present(<--debatable).  It became the language of international business and is spoken fluently by well over 2 billion people worldwide.  That and nobody wants to speak Spanish or Dutch :)

Comment: @maple_shaft: In the 1700's, the French and English fought throughout the world (including the US).  In US schools, it's called the "French and Indian Wars", but the indigenous tribes where more mercenary forces than anything else.  The French won every single encounter.  I would dispute the power of Great Britain.  However.  The English language came to dominate in spite of the English military losses.  History is a peculiar thing.

Comment: @maple_shaft - "nobody wants to speak Spanish"?! ... do you even know in how many countries it is spoken? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language

Comment: @S.Lott: You mean the part where the British Empire was the biggest empire to ever exist, and occupied 25% of the entire world's surface? That kind of "not powerful"?

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm not talking about the world.  I'm talking about the US in the 1700's where the French had the British hemmed into a small area along the coast.  I'm talking about the British losing military engagements in this theater only.  The French clearly controlled most of what became he US.  Yet. The US wound up speaking English.  Not French.  The same analysis applies to C.  It's a complex history with lots of influencing factors.  There's no trivial, pat answer.

Comment: @Idigas It was a joke seriously I meant no offense!  But sorry to break the history lesson but this is getting a little offtopic.  We should probably take it to chat?

Comment: @S.Lott Although you may find it hard to belive, military conquest had little to do with the power of the British Empire. The BE mainly came about through trade and colonisation. When India wanted independence there's aquote from Ghandi along the lines of "3,000,000 British cannot maintian control over 500,000,000 Indians without the consent of the Indians." He was quite right.

Comment: @S.Lott: "French and Indian War" was won by British - they drove French out of Canada. Off topic, of course.

Comment: "Although you may find it hard to believe"?  I find that a bit insulting.  My point is that history is complex and involves a lot of complex forces.  I can find one (small) example where the forces are not obvious.  How does that lead me to have trouble believing in historical facts?  The history of the C language is equally complex, with lots of hidden forces and nuances.  Would I have trouble believing that, too?

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: "was won by British"?  That's the subtlety.  I don't think they "drove" the French out of Canada.  I think other forces were at work to shift the balance of power.  The military history is pretty clear: the British lost a lot of fights.  Yet.  The language won out.  C's history is similarly complex and difficult to interpret.

Comment: @S.Lott The French didn't win every single encounter.  Just looking at North America they won a majority; but losing 4 of the 5 major battles in NA during 1559/60 resulted in a crushing defeat in the theater.  The captures of Forts Ticonderoga and Niagara, The Plains of Abraham, and the battle of Restigouche were all British victories.  By cutting off supply/reinforcement the latter made the French victory at Sainte-Foy irrelevant.

Comment: @DanNeely: Excellent point.  The history is subtle.  Fort Dusquense, 1754, defeat for the Brits.  Eventually, the fort did fall.  But it was solidly French territory from there down to Louisiana.  Where they still speak French.  Yet, English predominates.  The history of C is similarly subtle.

Comment: @S.Lott: What is exactly the subtlety? Nouvelle France was occupied and their governor surrendered to British in 1760.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: The subtlety remains this one fact.  The French occupied more of the US than the British.  The US had to purchase giant swaths of land from the French.  yet.  Except in Louisiana, the dominant language was English.  That's the subtlety.  There's no **simple** explanation for English being the dominant language in the US.  This parallels my point about C.  There's no **simple** explanation for the prevalence of C.  Yes. There were French defeats.  There were also English defeats.  It's not **simple**.

Comment: @S.Lott The reason there isn't a large Francophone region in the US despite a large chunk having been historically owned by France is that the French never established any large scale upstream settlements in the Mississippi valley when they had ownership of the area.  As a result when British/American settlers began moving into the area they quickly grew to outnumber the handful of French traders/trappers in the area.  This is also why Ontario is primarily an English speaking region today despite having been owned by France in the past.

Comment: @DanNeely: Which reinforces my point about C being the root of many languages.  Migrations.  Wars.  Economics.  Politics.  Lots and lots of factors lead to prevalence of national languages and technical languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new programming language, having a syntax similar with popular existing languages makes learning easier for your new users. Especially if many concepts are similar between languages.

Also I think that C-style syntax is relatively easy to read. To compare with Pascal, using symbols "{" and "}" for blocks of code is more legible than "begin" and "end", which are optically very similar to identifiers. Python is even more legible, but including whitespace in syntax opens a new set of problems with editing. Another example: Lisp and JavaScript share a few ideas, but when the same thing is written in C-style syntax, it is less obscure.

I am sure many people would disagree with the second paragraph, because everyone has their own favourite language, but I think that the popularity of C-style syntax is partially a historical coincidence, but partially it also shows that authors of C made a few good decisions.

Answer (score -1):

Programming languages evolve over time just like natural languages, with some older languages influencing that evolution in a stronger way than others, while others fade into obscurity and their influence is harder to trace on the surface level, that is, syntax.

C's influence comes from many sources - it's low level, widespread, had backing in both Unix and Microsoft circles. It's also survival of the fittest issue - it's easy to see terse C-like syntax had more appeal than the verbose Algol-derived syntax of Pascal and other competitors of C in the 1970s and 1980s. Hence it was widely adopted by languages that came after it.

With present growth of importance of multithreaded programming and functional languages being particularly well-suited to it, I'd say we'll see their influence grow in the future. Case in point: Python, which even made that list in the question post.

*[A nice timeline view of language history to ponder upon](http://www.levenez.com/lang/)*

Comment: You got it wrong. Both PASCAL and C are ALGOL descendants.

Comment: True, but Algol itself is Fortran descendant and picked some of the constructs I was referring to there (program, end, subroutine compared to c's brackets). Still, what I had in mind was in fact Algol-like syntax. Edited.

Comment: **terse C-like syntax had more appeal then verbose Algol-derived syntax of Pascal and other competitors of C in the 70's and 80's** +1 for that. _begin_ programmers are humans too _end_ _begin_ [those who believed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth) that it's convenient to map punctuation signs to words like begin-end lost their battle to curly braces _end of story_

Comment: I see no evidence that C syntax is less obscure, except in the sense that most developers know C or some sort of C-related language, and so it looks more familiar.  AFAICT, C won over Pascal because of its structure, and the fact that implementations didn't have to roll their own linking, not syntax.

Comment: @David-From what I remember, one of the reasons C won out over other languages was because of the relative ease of accessing memory in C (ie. pointers). I know they are fround upon now, but back when 1 KB of RAM was a lot of memory, that was a very powerful feature of the language. I know other languages provided pointer like features, but none as easily as C.

Answer (score -3):

Most of the languages you list have virtually nothing to do with C apart from irrelevant syntactic similarities. The only two actual C derivatives are Objective-C and C++.

Comment: If we are not considering syntax, then the only differences between any languages are the availability of general language constructs (loops, conditionals, variables, abstractions of these like classes and closures, etc...) and that they all equate to behavior of machine code.  All low level languages are similar to each other and all high-level languages are extremely similar to each other at that point.

Comment: You shouldn't think about a language as what functionality it has, but how it communicates application behavior.  Your source code is your lowest level of documentation and one writes source code for **people** and **NOT** for **machines**.  If we wrote code strictly for machines then we would all be coding in assembly.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Quite right! I was asked in an interview to explain the difference between machine language (assembler) and programming language. My answer was: "Machine language is for machines, programming language is for programmers."

Comment: @maple_shaft: The syntax is irrelevant as to it's communication to *people*. If I replaced an English word with a different spelling, English would still be the same language. The syntactic form is irrelevant, what's communicative is the language semantics.

Comment: @DeadMG: But the question is *about* syntax. You can consider the syntactic similarities to be irrelevant, but the person asking the question wants to know *why* these irrelevant similarities *exist*.